# How to get the Text of the Radiobuttonlist?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server" onMouseUp="Myf()">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>        
    </asp:RadioButtonList>




function Myf() {
            var list = document.getElementById("<%=rbl.ClientID %>"); 
           var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var selected;
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                alert(inputs[i].innerHTML);

            }        

        }
```

I'm getting the value of Radiobuttonlist. How to get the Text of the Radiobuttonlist?

Comment: Can you provide this code in Jsfiddle

Comment: Radiobuttons do not have text. Text is in label element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the radio buttons do not have text in your code

Second, if you look at the source of the resulting html page, you can see that the radio buttons have labels that store the text.
So you can look for `label` instead of `input` in your function and it will get the text

```
    function Myf() {
        var list = document.getElementById("<%=rbl.ClientID %>");
        var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("label");
        var selected;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            alert(inputs[i].innerHTML);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solves your issue, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the getAttribute() method.

```
element.getAttribute("Text");
```

More info on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.getAttribute

Comment: sorry, I'm getting Null Reference; alert(inputs[i].getAttribute("Text"));

Comment: RadioButtonList is rendered as table so document.getElementById("<%=rbl.ClientID %>"); will be a table not checked element

Answer (score 1):

To get text you have to put "label" instead of "input" in getelement.

try like this:

```
    var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("label");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>        
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*="rdl"],[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            console.log($(this).next('label').html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function Myf() {
        $("#<%=rbl.ClientID %>").find('input').each(function () {
            var this_input = $(this);
            alert($("#<%=rbl.ClientID %>").find('label[for="' + this_input.attr('id') + '"]').text());
        })

    }
```